# What vertical bar('|') means in android?

Tags: java, android, wakelock, powermanager

For example:

```
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK|
        PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP|PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "Alarm");
```

**What does the ' | ' character mean?**

---

More details about the problem:

I'm asking this because when I instantiate the wakelock with only `PowerManager.AQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` the program stops working, where as when I use the way above, it works fine.

I'm wondering if the cause of this is because the program ignore the `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` tag and it ends up not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, that symbol (`|`) is a bitwise OR. It's used in a lot of different languages and environments outside of Android.

It's usage is:

"X|Y : if X or Y is 1, then the result is 1"

In your specific case it's being used to create a bit field. Besure to review the Android power manager code base  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

Possible flags for this API are:

```
PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK        = 0x01 
SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK     = 0x06
SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK  = 0x0a
FULL_WAKE_LOCK           = 0x1a
```

These are mutually exclusive (you can only pick one), but you can "OR in" some other flags:

```
ON_AFTER_RELEASE         = 0x20000000
ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP    = 0x10000000
```

So once your code runs it ORs these flags together resulting in:

```
    0x20000000
  | 0x10000000
  | 0x0000001a
---------------
    0x3000001a
```

---

> I'm asking this because when i instantiate the wakelock with only "PowerManager.AQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP" the program stops working

That's because you ***have to*** pick one of the levels of wake lock (`PARTIAL`, `SCREEN_DIM`, `SCREEN_BRIGHT`, or `FULL`), you're trying to run with just one of the optional wake lock flags...

Answer (score 7):

The | is a bitwise or, and it goes beyond Android.  It is often used to stuff multiple options into one parameter.

So a function of the form f(X|Y|Z) means the function should use options X, Y and Z.  Of course, X, Y and Z should be appropriately coded to ensure | will preserve their values.

Answer (score 2):

[From the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

bitwise inclusive OR    => |

The Bitwise inclusive OR ( | ) operator performs the bitwise inclusive OR operation on each parallel pair of bits of two operands. In each pair, the result is 1, if either first or second bit is 1 (or both are 1). Otherwise the result is 0. Lets see the table of using inclusive operations.
Lets understand the inclusive OR operations using truth table:

```
    (OR)

 A   B   Result
 0   0   0
 1   0   1
 0   1   1
 1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at constants most often used with `|` in the type of example you've shown, their values are powers of 2.  For example:

```
Options.OPTION1 = 1;
Options.OPTION2 = 2;
Options.OPTION3 = 4;
Options.OPTION4 = 8;
```

In binary (Note I have omitted the 0b prefix for ease of reading):

```
Options.OPTION1 = 0001;
Options.OPTION2 = 0010;
Options.OPTION3 = 0100;
Options.OPTION4 = 1000;
```

If you `OR` Options.OPTION1 and Options.OPTION3, the result is 0101;

```
Options.OPTION1 | Options.OPTION3 => 0101
```

This enables you to pack multiple values into one since each combination of options is unique.

You can "extract" the options from the packed value by ANDing the options:

```
packedValue = Options.OPTION1 | Options.OPTION3;


packedValue & Options.OPTION3 => true;
packedValue & Options.OPTION4 => false;
```

Since

```
0101 AND 0100 => 0100 => true
```

and

```
0101 AND 1000 => 0000 => false
```